# Uninitialized Backreference in Substitution

Tags: regex, perl

Assuming that I must do this substitution using a single substitution, what is the preferred method to avoid this error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $2 in concatenation (.) or string at -e line 1.
```

With this Perl code:

```
perl -e 'use strict;use warnings;my $str="a";$str=~s/(a)|(b)/$1foo$2/gsmo;'
```

The goal here is to either print "afoo" or "foob" depending on what `$str` contains.

I can use `no warnings;` but then I am worried I will miss other "real" warnings. I also know that using one pattern makes this convoluted but my actual pattern is much more complicated.

If you care the actual replacements are closer to:

```
#!perl
my $search = q~(document\.domain.*?</script>)|(</head>)~;
my $search_re = qr/$search/smo;
my $replace = q("$1
<script src=\"/library.js\"></script>
$2");
while (<*.tmpl>) {
  my $str = fead_file($_);
  $str =~ s/$search_re/$replace/gee;
}
```

But even more complicated, basically the above code just reads from a DB to get the search & replace and then does them to the template. Having to run this script twice with every commit would introduce too much overhead, apparently... so says them...

Comment: Why not just do two different search&replace operations inside your loop?  The overhead should be undetectable compared to the time it takes just to read the files.

Comment: The loop is a library I cannot change. I can only provide the substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could:

```
my $replace = q("@{[$1||'']}
<script src=\"/library.js\"></script>
@{[$2||'']}");
```

(using // instead of || on 5.10+)

Answer (score 1):

Still works with /g:

```
s/(a)|(b)/ ($1 // '') . 'foo' . ($2 // '') /ge
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't find both "a" and "b" when you specifically say OR (`|`). Also, you cannot concatenate the strings by placing the variable name next to the text, e.g. `$1foo`.

I'm not quite sure what you are saying about overhead, but you do need to check the match in order to do a correct replacement.

```
s/(a)/$1 . "foo"/ge || s/(b)/"foo" . $1/ge;
```

This might work. If the first one works, the second won't be executed (short circuit OR).

Comment: Look at the "closer to" real example; the substitution is a /g, so presumably both substitutions could occur and short-circuiting won't work.

Comment: @ysth Ah, I see your point. However, does `$1` and `$2` really work in an OR situation? I don't have access to perl at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to ikegami's solution, if you want to hold the replacement in a variable you can call a code reference in `s///e` passing it the captures.

```
#!perl
my $search = q~(document\.domain.*?</script>)|(</head>)~;
my $search_re = qr/$search/smo;
my $replace = sub {
    my $one = shift || '';
    my $two = shift || '';
    return qq($one\n<script src="/library.js"></script>\n$two);
}
while (<*.tmpl>) {
  my $str = fead_file($_);
  $str =~ s/$search_re/$replace->($1, $2)/ge;
}
```